# subfigure | getting it working with tikzpicture-matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfloats, tikz-matrix, subfig

Using the subfig package. For simple docs where the sub-figure graphics are included, works fine. For example, the following code works perfectly.

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage[caption=false,position=top]{subfig}

 \begin{document}
   Subfigure demo -- works with included graphics

 \begin{figure}[h]
 \centering
 \subfloat[first sub-figure]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\columnwidth]{fig1.eps}
  }
 
 \subfloat[second sub-figure]{
 \includegraphics[width=0.6\columnwidth]{fig2.eps}
 }
 \end{figure}
```

But, as soon as I try to use tikzpicture with \matrix (instead of an included .eps file), crashes and burns.

Simple tikzpictures work fine.  For example, something like the following works as expected:

```
 \documentclass{article}

  \usepackage{tikz}
     \usetikzlibrary{decorations,shapes,arrows,matrix,positioning}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage[caption=false,position=top]{subfig}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{figure}[h]
 \centering
 \subfloat[first diag]{
 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,4) -- (0,4) -- (0,0);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 }

 \subfloat[second diag]{
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (2,2) circle (3cm);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 }
 \end{figure} 
 \end{document}
```

But, the moment I try something involving \matrix (which I use a lot), I get the following sort of error.

```
 ! Undefined control sequence.
 <argument> \pgf@matrix@last@nextcell@options 
                                         
 l.29 }
 ? 
 Process has been terminated ...
```

Here is a MWE of an example using tizkpictures to draw acyclic graphs. The tikzpicture code compiles perfectly, on its own. It simply refuses to when imbedded in a subfloat using the subfig package.

Pointers to the obvious mistakes I'm (surely) making happily welcome!

```
\documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{decorations,shapes,arrows,matrix,positioning}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{float}

  \usepackage[caption=false,position=top]{subfig}

\begin{document}

Subfigure demo - refuses to work with tikzpicture-matrix

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\subfloat[first life-cycle]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,->,shorten >=1.5pt,transform canvas={scale=0.95},line width=0.75pt]
\matrix (a) [matrix of nodes,row sep=0.5em, column sep=3em, every node/.style={circle,draw,font=\small\sffamily,minimum width=1cm}] { 1 & 2 & 3 \\};
\path[>=stealth,font=\small] (a-1-1) edge node[below] {$S_0$} (a-1-2);
\path[>=stealth,font=\small] (a-1-2) edge node[below] {$S_1$} (a-1-3);
\path[>=stealth,->,font=\small] (a-1-3) edge [bend right=55] node [above,near start] {$S_2F_3$} (a-1-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\subfloat[second life-cycle]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,->,shorten >=1.5pt,transform canvas={scale=0.95},line width=0.75pt]
\matrix (a) [matrix of nodes,row sep=0.5em, column sep=3em, every node/.style={circle,draw,font=\small\sffamily,minimum width=1cm}] { 1 & 2 & 3 \\};
\path[>=stealth,font=\small] (a-1-1) edge node[below] {$S_0$} (a-1-2);
\path[>=stealth,font=\small] (a-1-2) edge node[below] {$S_1$} (a-1-3);
\path[>=stealth,->,font=\small] (a-1-2) edge [bend right=50] node [above,near start] {$S_1F_2$} (a-1-1) ;
\path[>=stealth,->,font=\small] (a-1-3) edge [bend right=55] node [above,near start] {$S_2F_3$} (a-1-1) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but a clue as to why `\subfloat` messes up.  The only difference between the two is `\savebox`.

```
\documentclass{article}

  \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations,shapes,arrows,matrix,positioning}
  %\usepackage{graphicx}
  %\usepackage{float}

  %\usepackage[caption=false,position=top]{subfig}
  
\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\setbox\tempbox=\hbox{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,->,shorten >=1.5pt,scale=0.95,line width=0.75pt]
\matrix (a) [matrix of nodes,row sep=0.5em, column sep=3em, every node/.style={circle,draw,font=\small\sffamily,minimum width=1cm}]
  { 1 & 2 & 3 \\};
\path[>=stealth,font=\small] (a-1-1) edge node[below] {$S_0$} (a-1-2);
\path[>=stealth,font=\small] (a-1-2) edge node[below] {$S_1$} (a-1-3);
\path[>=stealth,->,font=\small] (a-1-3) edge [bend right=55] node [above,near start] {$S_2F_3$} (a-1-1);
\draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}\usebox\tempbox

\savebox{\tempbox}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,->,shorten >=1.5pt,scale=0.95,line width=0.75pt]
\matrix (a) [matrix of nodes,row sep=0.5em, column sep=3em, every node/.style={circle,draw,font=\small\sffamily,minimum width=1cm}]
  { 1 & 2 & 3 \\};
\path[>=stealth,font=\small] (a-1-1) edge node[below] {$S_0$} (a-1-2);
\path[>=stealth,font=\small] (a-1-2) edge node[below] {$S_1$} (a-1-3);
\path[>=stealth,->,font=\small] (a-1-3) edge [bend right=55] node [above,near start] {$S_2F_3$} (a-1-1);
\draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}\usebox\tempbox
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the last example the package `subcaption` behaves better, as long as you don't use `transform canvas=`.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,shapes,arrows,matrix,positioning}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{subcaption}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
        
    Subfigure demo - refuses to work with tikzpicture-matrix
    
    \begin{figure}[htp!]
        \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}% changed <<<<<
    \subcaption{first life-cycle}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,->,shorten >=1.5pt,
                %transform canvas={scale=0.95},
                line width=0.75pt]          
                \matrix (a) [matrix of nodes,row sep=0.5em, column sep=3em, every node/.style={circle,draw,font=\small\sffamily,minimum width=1cm}] { 1 & 2 & 3 \\};
                \path[>=stealth,font=\small] (a-1-1) edge node[below] {$S_0$} (a-1-2);
                \path[>=stealth,font=\small] (a-1-2) edge node[below] {$S_1$} (a-1-3);
                \path[>=stealth,->,font=\small] (a-1-3) edge [bend right=55] node [above,near start] {$S_2F_3$} (a-1-1);
            \end{tikzpicture}
     \end{subfigure}
 
 \bigskip
        
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}% changed <<<<<
    \subcaption{second sub-figure}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,->,shorten >=1.5pt,
                %transform canvas={scale=0.95},
                line width=0.75pt]
                \matrix (a) [matrix of nodes,row sep=0.5em, column sep=3em, every node/.style={circle,draw,font=\small\sffamily,minimum width=1cm}] { 1 & 2 & 3 \\};
                \path[>=stealth,font=\small] (a-1-1) edge node[below] {$S_0$} (a-1-2);
                \path[>=stealth,font=\small] (a-1-2) edge node[below] {$S_1$} (a-1-3);
                \path[>=stealth,->,font=\small] (a-1-2) edge [bend right=50] node [above,near start] {$S_1F_2$} (a-1-1) ;
                \path[>=stealth,->,font=\small] (a-1-3) edge [bend right=55] node [above,near start] {$S_2F_3$} (a-1-1) ;
            \end{tikzpicture}
     \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure} 
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks -- I do routinely use transform canvas (which you obviously saw, since you had to comment it out), but thats a minor point. I'm still really curious why this doesn't work with subfig.  At all.

Comment: @Johnny Canuck Well ... I guess the why merits another question

Comment: I believe `transform canvas`  turns off the bounding box.

Answer (score 0):

You pass the `\matrix` as an argument to another command, so you need `ampersand replacement`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,shapes,arrows,matrix,positioning}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false,position=top]{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\subfloat[first life-cycle]{%
  \makebox[0.4\columnwidth]{\begin{tikzpicture}[
    >=stealth,
    ->,
    shorten >=1.5pt,
    transform canvas={scale=0.95},
    line width=0.75pt
  ]
  \matrix (a) [
    matrix of nodes,
    row sep=0.5em,
    column sep=3em,
    every node/.style={circle,draw,font=\small\sffamily,minimum width=1cm},
    ampersand replacement=\&,
  ] { 1 \& 2 \& 3 \\};
  \path[>=stealth,font=\small] (a-1-1) edge node[below] {$S_0$} (a-1-2);
  \path[>=stealth,font=\small] (a-1-2) edge node[below] {$S_1$} (a-1-3);
  \path[>=stealth,->,font=\small] (a-1-3) edge [bend right=55] node [above,near start]
    {$S_2F_3$} (a-1-1);
  \end{tikzpicture}\rule[-5ex]{0pt}{15ex}}%
}\qquad
\subfloat[second life-cycle]{%
  \makebox[0.4\columnwidth]{\begin{tikzpicture}[
    >=stealth,
    ->,
    shorten >=1.5pt,
    transform canvas={scale=0.95},
    line width=0.75pt,
    ampersand replacement=\&,
  ]
  \matrix (a) [
    matrix of nodes,
    row sep=0.5em, 
    column sep=3em,
    every node/.style={circle,draw,font=\small\sffamily,minimum width=1cm}
  ] { 1 \& 2 \& 3 \\};
  \path[>=stealth,font=\small] (a-1-1) edge node[below] {$S_0$} (a-1-2);
  \path[>=stealth,font=\small] (a-1-2) edge node[below] {$S_1$} (a-1-3);
  \path[>=stealth,->,font=\small] (a-1-2) edge [bend right=50] node [above,near start]
    {$S_1F_2$} (a-1-1) ;
  \path[>=stealth,->,font=\small] (a-1-3) edge [bend right=55] node [above,near start]
    {$S_2F_3$} (a-1-1) ;
  \end{tikzpicture}\rule[-5ex]{0pt}{15ex}}%
}

\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

I added an invisible rule and a boxing level in order to get the bounding box acceptable. There are possibly better methods.

[image]

Comment: Wonderful. Thanks. Yet another thing I didn't know (being, ampersand replacement)